# Three modifications of connectedness

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question arose in my research of generalized connectedness (see [this draft article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/connectedness.pdf) for the overall idea, but beware that the draft is yet too preliminary and unreadable, however I hope you can understand the overall idea from the draft):

Let $U$ is a set, $r$ is a binary relation on $\mathcal{P} U$. I call $r$ a *connector*.

Informal note: The relation $r$ of two sets $A$ and $B$ represents that $A$ and $B$ are in some sense "near" or "touch". For example $r$ may be a proximity.

I will call a connector $r$ *extendable* when

$ \forall X_0, Y_0, X_1, Y_1 \in \mathcal{P} U : (X_1 \cap Y_1 = \emptyset
   \wedge X_0 r Y_0 \wedge X_1 \supseteq X_0
   \wedge Y_1 \supseteq Y_0 \Rightarrow X_1 r
   Y_1) . $

Below I will require that $r$ is extendable.

I will define the set $\mathrm{CC} (r)$ of connected subsets of $U$ by the
formula

$ \mathrm{CC} (r) = \lbrace A \in \mathcal{P} U |
   \forall X, Y \in \mathcal{P} A \setminus \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace : (X \cup Y = A
   \wedge X \cap Y = \emptyset \Rightarrow X r
   Y) \rbrace . $

As I mentioned above, $r$ may be a proximity and in this case $\mathrm{CC}(r)$ is proximal connectedness, that is a set a $A$ is connected iff every partition of the set a $A$ consists of two near sets.

As an other important example $ArB$ may mean that the topological closure (given some topological space) of the set $A$ in the subspace generated by the set $A\cup B$ intersects $B$ or the closure of $B$ intersect $A$. This is equivalent to the classic definition of connectedness of a set on topological space, because it happens if and only if $A$ and $B$ are not both open-closed on $A\cup B$.

There are other examples of connectedness following this scheme: graph connectedness, digraph strong connectedness, uniform connectedness, etc. (see [my draft article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/connectedness.pdf))

I will define connectors $\gamma (r)$ and $\beta (r)$ by the formulas (for every $A, B \in \mathcal{P} U$)

$ A \gamma (r) B \Leftrightarrow \exists X \in
   \mathcal{P} A, Y \in \mathcal{P} B : X r Y. $

$ A \beta (r) B \Leftrightarrow A \cup B \in
   \mathrm{CC} (r) . $

Conjecture: $\mathrm{CC} (\gamma (r)) = \mathrm{CC} (\beta (r)) = \mathrm{CC} (r)$.

If it is wrong I want to see the counter-examples with which it fails and
additional condition under which it is indeed true.

In [the above mentioned draft article](http://www.mathematics21.org/binaries/connectedness.pdf) I proved that $\mathrm{CC}(\beta(r)) \subseteq \mathrm{CC}(r) \subseteq \mathrm{CC}(\gamma(r))$.

Comment: You might increase the number of responses by giving some motivation (why generalize connectedness?) or by comparing familiar ideas (how is it a generalization of connectedness?)

Comment: @David: I think this is answered in the linked article.

Comment: @David: I added a reference to the article, where the problem arises, above the question. Is the idea understandable from my too rough draft?

Comment: @Martin: I saw the link, but I maintain that including motivation and relationship to familiar ideas might increase the number of responses.

@Porton: I am not a topologist, so perhaps it is not surprising that your motivation is unclear to me

Comment: I voted to close as "too localized."  It really seems way too specific with very little motivation.

Comment: @Noah: I wonder, do you consider my above mentioned article too specific?! In fact it is very general. Or to be too specific and very general are compatible accordingly you opinion? If the article is not too specific, then the question is also not too specific. It seems that you've not looked into my article before voting. Bad.

Comment: http://www.mathematics21.org/abel-prize.html

Comment: @Noah: I think that the question could be left up a bit longer until someone comes along with a more specialized viewpoint or priorexperience of wh this kind of stuff does/doesn't work. (Should I make this a vote *not* to close, as it were, or have I misunderstood the new system?)

Comment: @Harry: on this occasion I'd prefer us to play the ball, and not the man

Comment: @Porton: In the definition of CC(r), did you mean to say that X and Y are elements of PA, i.e. subsets of A?  In the question, you wrote that they're elements of A.  (Your draft article seems to agree with what I'm suggesting, though.)



Comment: Also, it seems to me you could at least explain your conception of what the relation r represents, since many people will not care to click on the link in order to find out.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, they are elements of PA. I corrected the error in the question.

Comment: @Dan: The relation r of two sets A and B represents that A and B are in some sense "near" or "touch". For example r may be a proximity. As an other important example ArB may mean that the topological closure (given some topological space) of the set A in the subspace generated by the set $A\cup B$ does not intersect B neither the closure of B does intersect A. This is equivalent to the classic definition of connectedness of a set on topological space, because it happens if and only if A and B are open-closed on $A\cup B$. Should I add this to the question, or having here in comment is enough?

Comment: Oh, in my last comment I messed r and not-r (negation of r) when telling about connectedness regarding topological space.

Answer (score 3):

First let me note that I agree with many of the comments and my answering the question should not be taken as disagreement.  In particular, I find something off-putting about asking such a question on a topic about which you are writing a paper.  It would be one thing if this were a mere curiosity (questions of the form "does such and such approach lead anywhere" come up a lot, and can be ok if phrased right).  This seems more of the form "I don't feel like checking the details; could you prove my lemmas or give me counterexamples".  Nonetheless I had some time and felt like playing around with some random idea which has nothing to do with the conference I'm currently at (on game theory).  So I'm answering against my better judgement.

Define the disjointness relation $\delta$ by $A\delta B \Leftrightarrow A\cap B = \emptyset$.  Here are some easy things to check:

1) If $r$ is a connector then so is $r\cap\delta$ and $CC(r) = CC(r\cap\delta)$.  (Here I'm assuming "connector" means a relation which satisfies the monotonicity property you specified; that wasn't entirely clear)

2) $r\subseteq\gamma(r)$ and $\gamma(r)\cap\delta\subseteq r\cap\delta$, so $\gamma(r)\cap\delta = r\cap\delta$.

3) $CC(\gamma(r)) = CC(\gamma(r)\cap\delta)=CC(r\cap\delta)=CC(r)$

As for the question of $\beta(r)$, it should be noted that as you defined it (or, as I'm assuming you were meaning to define it) $\beta(r)$ is not a connector.  Suppose it were.  Then $A\in CC(r)$ implies $A\beta(r)\emptyset$.  By the definition of a connector, $B\beta(r)\emptyset$ whenever $A\subseteq B$, so $B\in CC(r)$.  That is to say, any superset of a connected set is connected.  This is usually not true; say, if $r$ defines the usual connectedness of a discrete space.  So it's not clear that it makes sense to ask about $CC(\beta(r))$, because as a set it may not have the properties you'd expect for a notion of connectedness.

Comment: To be a connector the monotonicity property (which I call extendability) is not necessary. I edited my question to clarify the difference between connector and extendable connector.

Comment: Why $\gamma(r)\cap\delta\subseteq r\cap\delta$? It seems you mistake here.

Comment: I was assuming what you are now calling extendability, because you hadn't clarified that they were intended to be separate definitions. So if you hadn't meant to imply that you can ignore my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of $\beta(r)$ it's obvios that $CC(\beta(r))=CC(r)$.

$CC(\beta(r))=\{A\subseteq U\ |\ \forall X,Y\subset A,\ X\not=\emptyset\not=Y \land X\cup Y=A \land X\cap Y=\emptyset$ $\implies X\cup Y=A\in CC(r)\}=\{A\subseteq U\ | \ A\in CC(r)\}$.

Now assume $A\in CC(\gamma(r))$ and $X,Y\subset A$ non empty such that $X\cup Y=A$ and $X\cap Y=\emptyset$, then $X\gamma(r) Y$. So $\exists N\subset X \land M\subset Y$ such that $NrM$. Now if $r$ is extendable, we have $XrY$. So we can conclude that $A\in CC(r)$.

Is this what you were asking?